# cannot find module '@angular/core' visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I am new to angular + asp.net core

i am create sample project of angular 4 with .net core

but it keepshowing dependencies not installed

[image]

**visual studio 15.5.2**

**Typescript version 2.6.2**

**Microsoft Typescript sdk 2.6.2**

**npm version 5.5.1**

in my other machine its work perfectly but not in this pc
please help!!

MY package.json file is below

```
{
  "name": "Angular_CRUD",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you run `npm install`?

Comment: @AyushGupta i need to run this command every time? when i create new project.

Comment: Yes, whenever a dependency is added to a package.json, run that command.

Comment: @AyushGupta after npm install command when i start my project i got this errorOne or more errors occurred. (Cannot find module './wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json

Comment: how are you starting it?

Comment: try running `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js` . Source: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/99

Comment: @AyushGupta in my other pc , i did not run npm install command , not run webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js , it automatically installed all node_modules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run

`npm install` inside the folder to install the dependencies.

If this does not work, remove `package-lock.json` and try again

Comment: it should be install automatically . not manually as now i have latest versions of visual studio,typescript and npm

Comment: yes bro . its working but it should run automatically now. do you have any idea about that. because now it is feature that vs 2017 provide

Comment: @ShahNIral unless you disable that feature. For example, I disabled auto-install on `package.json` save for obvious reasons.

Comment: @AluanHaddad i did not disabled  anything .then also its not working that is my question

Comment: @ShahNIral Did you ever get his resolved? I get the same thing doing the build using VS 2107.